# Encrypt in PHP 7 decrypt in Node JS

Tags: php, node.js, encryption, php-7

In PHP 5.6 there were plenty of solutions that worked perfectly that were based on http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php

For example

```
public function encrypt($data)
{
    //don't use default php padding which is '\0'
    $pad = $this->blocksize - (strlen($data) % $this->blocksize);
    $data = $data . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
    return bin2hex(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
        $this->encryptKey,
        $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $this->iv));
}
```

But PHP7 has a **WARNING** that discourages using this function.

*"This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.1.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged."*

Any ideas for safe encryption using keywords on both ends; PHP + Node.js?

Comment: This explains why its deprecated and makes a suggestion on what to use instead http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.deprecated.php

Comment: Try using `openssl_encrypt` http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php

Comment: As suggested, use openssl, not only because LibMcrypt is deprecated, but also because NodeJS Crypto module relays on openssl, so you can expect good compatibility of algorithms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LibMcrypt was abandoned in 2007. More information https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mcrypt-viking-funeral

You have to use openssl encrypt http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php

**PHP**

```
<?php
$textToEncrypt = "Secret Text to Encrypt";
$encryptionMethod = 'aes-256-cbc';
$secretHash = "315a5504d921f8327f73a356d2bbcbf1"; // <---- you have to use some persistent key.

$iv_size = openssl_cipher_iv_length($encryptionMethod);
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($iv_size);

//To encrypt
$encryptedMessage = openssl_encrypt($textToEncrypt, $encryptionMethod, $secretHash, 0, $iv);

//Concatenate iv with data
$encryptedMessageWithIv = bin2hex($iv) . $encryptedMessage;

//To Decrypt
$iv_size = openssl_cipher_iv_length($encryptionMethod);
$iv = hex2bin(substr($encryptedMessageWithIv, 0, $iv_size * 2));

$decryptedMessage = openssl_decrypt(substr($encryptedMessageWithIv, $iv_size * 2), $encryptionMethod, $secretHash, 0, $iv);

echo "Encrypted: $encryptedMessageWithIv <br>Decrypted: $decryptedMessage";
```

Try it here https://3v4l.org/r9pYv

**Node.JS**(i really not a node.js programmer, there can be more efficient way)

```
var data = "ad699a2537ec2a7f699acbf97ca0080eh3z5EgvnTAvlc76YeR6HdWPmkDDt+pHiG//qo7xnqyQ=";
var key = "315a5504d921f8327f73a356d2bbcbf1";
var iv = new Buffer(data.substring(0,32), 'hex');
var dec = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc',key,iv);
var decrypted = Buffer.concat([dec.update(new Buffer(data.substring(32),'base64')), dec.final()]);
console.log('DECRYPTED TEXT: '+decrypted.toString());
```

Try here: https://repl.it/FQyo/2

Comment: This gives 3 different outputs for 3 recent PHP7 versions, that's weird and not common when it comes to decrypting on node js

Comment: Of course - it will be diffrent outputs even you are using one version of PHP on every new run(because of initialization vector - iv) - this is the key aim of strong cryptography. 
What you need is only to set some static key for $secretHash variable in both - nodejs and php.

Comment: how to maintain compatability with node js then if the output keeps changing?

Comment: Ok. challenge accepted. I updated answer with node.js part. I set persistent key in php (note php link updated too)
You can replace data with ANY one of the PHP link output and see THE MAGIC of cryptography )

Comment: works like charm, let me hear other opinions before i accept your answer. thanks

Comment: How to do this in opposite side?

Comment: Can you please provide me with the encryption function for the Node js